# Summing unique money currencies in csv file with java

Tags: java

I'm struggling to make a program which will make sum for unique money currencies. I know how to read from file but can't find a way to sum from CSV file. CSV file looks like this (forgot to put that there is first column in CSV files with country, so IDK if map would work):

```
EUR, 24  
EUR, 76  
YEN, 66 
YEN, 90  
USD, 87 
USD, 5
```

Code

```
File file = new File("file.csv");
Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);
ArrayList<String> rows = new ArrayList<String>();

while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = reader.nextLine();
    System.out.println(line);
    rows.add(line);
}

reader.close();
```

Comment: Use a `Map<String,Double>`

Comment: Maybe better use `Map<String, BigDecimal>`, but your example looks like a `Map<String, Integer>` would suffice...

Answer (score 3):

You can map lines to a custom `Money` type and then use [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) and [`Collectors.summingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingInt(java.util.function.ToIntFunction)). Assuming the amount is an integer, if not change the summing collector:

```
public class Money {
    private final String symbol;
    private final int amount;

    public Money(String line) {
        String[] values = line.split(", ");
        symbol = values[0];
        amount = Integer.parseInt(values[1]);
    }

    public String getSymbol() { return symbol; }
    public int getAmount() { return amount; }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Map<String, Integer> amounts = Files.lines(Paths.get("file.csv"))
            .map(Money::new)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Money::getSymbol, Collectors.summingInt(Money::getAmount)));
    System.out.println(amounts); // {YEN=156, EUR=100, USD=92}
}
```

Comment: Instead of `Files.readAllLines(...).stream()` why not just `Files.lines(...)`?